# Duplicate Stack Snippets from my own answer to my own answer

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Periodically, in questions, we'll answer a question that was asked, giving the solution that was *asked for*, by the person posting the question, but which is (in our (not necessarily so) humble opinion) not a recommended approach, or which contains poor practice or is more convoluted than need be. Sometimes, we'll show the jQuery approach (as requested), and then want to show a plain JavaScript approach.

Regardless, sometimes we'd like to post multiple approaches to the same problem in one answer.

With Stack Snippets™, we can simply copy the inserted HTML to another point in the answer and then click the 'edit the above snippet' link, in the preview. This *feels* a little overly-complex to me. Would it be possible to have a 'fork snippet into own answer' (phrasing could well be improved)?

Comment: Ooo, that would be neat. Especially if we could switch between the various forks without leaving the editor.